# Why the _id for the inserted mongo collection is generating with _str

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, database

I have a node app,where Iam inserting my json in to collection.On inserting in to collection Iam getting one unique _id generated.But it should be something like

```
"_id":"qwe13wdaf3g4g23g4"
```

But in my collection it is created as

```
"_id":{"_str":"qwe13wdaf3g4g23g4"}
```

How can we get this inserted only with _id

```
 var customerdata="{"name":"sam","age":30}";
 mongourl="*******";
 MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function(err, db) {
   if (err) {
         console.log( err);
             } else {

                   console.log('Connection established');
                   var collection =db.collection('customer');
                   collection.insert(customerdata,function(err,result) {
                     if (err) {
                               console.log(err);
                              } 
                              else {
                                    console.log('Inserted documents' + result.insertedIds);

                                }
                            });
                       }
                    });
```

How can we make sure that we getting _id with out any _str key.
Can someone help in this one
Thanks

Comment: This line `var customerdata="{"name":"sam","age":30}";` is giving error for me as "Un expected identifier". If I remove the quotes and execute the same code of yours it writing as expected `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f0af36305d8410d0723665"),
    "name" : "sam",
    "age" : 30
}`

Comment: Even though Iam not having " ",still getting _str